# Icons remains when force delete apk in /data/app/ folder

Tags: android

As the title said, I delete the apk file in `/data/app/` folder manually, but the icon is still in the app drawer. I know reboot phone can work, but is there some way can work without reboot? Thank you.

Comment: Restart launcher.

Comment: But do you know how to restart launcher without reboot? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `am start` adb shell command. It may be executed using adb or in your application in rooted device. You can't take control on other apps without root.